# Given X is Uni, Prove -X is Uni?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I had this problem from my last question:

Given that:
$X \sim \text{Uni}(a,b)$.

Then why does this say that: $-X \sim \text{Uni}(-a,-b)$

and in general how can I prove such claims?

Please show a formal explanation to help me understand every step.

My book only has this definition of the density function:

$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{b-a} &x \in [a,b] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

Comment: [Probability theory](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_theory) is [about the measure-theoretic foundations](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8587/290189) of stochastics.  The tag ([tag:probability-theory]) should be used for questions concerning this subject, not for questions about calculating a specific probability.  Use ([tag:probability]) instead, see also [meta](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1686/290189).

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: For transformations of random variables, see [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).

Comment: You must use the definition of a random variable, what is the definition that you have of a uniform random variable? Remember, to show something is a Uniform random variable, you have to use the definition or a theorem, but this one requires just the definition and a simple transformation.

Comment: I don't have definition, my books says for random variables the following is true: f(x)=...

Comment: @TeresaLisbon added what my book says

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Comment: I get it. Now, I am sure you already know what $f_X$ means, it is the *density* of the random variable $X$. From this, you must figure out the density of the random variable $-X$. If that density matches with the definition of $\mbox{Unif}(-b,-a)$ we are done. How do you figure out the density of a random variable in general? Have you done other examples?

Comment: that's the problem I never did so... can you show me in general?

Comment: It is simple. The probability that $X$ lies in a certain set, $A$, is $\int_{A} f_X dx$. That is the link. So for example, let $X \sim Unif[0,1]$. Then the probability that $0.25 \leq X \leq 0.75 $  is $\int_{0.25}^{0.75} \frac 1{1-0} dx = 0.75 - 0.25 = 0.5$. Just like that. Do you understand this equivalence? Have you seen it before? Then we can proceed to my next comment.

Comment: can you post a general calculation so I can understand the whole picture of how giving that X has specific distribution then I can use this for -X?

Comment: John there are two proofs down here and so many comments to make you understand things. I think you need to brush up your basics of statistics and probability then come back and read answers. I am sure will understand them.

Comment: There is a mistake in your question: given $X \sim \text{Uni}(a,b)$, it holds $-X \sim \text{Uni}(-b,-a)$ and not $-X \sim \text{Uni}(-a,-b)$. The first parameter is always smaller than the second.

Comment: @mag Thanks mag for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

In order to find the distribution of a random variable $Y$, one determines for example the socalled [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)
$$
F_Y(x)=\mathbb{P}[Y\leq x].
$$
The function you are given in your book is called [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Formal_definition) and in most applications and simple cases is related via
$$
F_Y(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf_Y(y)dy
$$
and
$$
f_Y(x)=\frac{d}{dx}F_Y(x)
$$
to the CDF which allows quick calculations forth and back.

Can you determine the CDF of $-X$ and relate it to the CDF of a $\text{Uni}(-b,-a)$ variable?

Comment: Sorry But I never heard of CDF and what is this big F? I only know f, plus why it's fY(x) it should be fX(x)

Comment: I gave you a quick definition of CDF of a random variable $Y$, as you already used the letter $X$. Big $F_Y$ then exactly is the CDF as defined above of a random variable $Y$ as $\mathbb{P}[Y\in(-\infty;x]]$; where $\mathbb{P}$ denotes the probability measure of the sample space given in the background.

Comment: Sorry but this confused me even more

Comment: The letter $\mathbb{P}$ denotes the probability measure. This notation allows you to formally discuss probability in a mathematical setting. So for example $\mathbb{P}[X\in[a;b]]$ in your case denotes the probability that $X$ lies in the interval $[a;b]$. For this choice of $X$ it clearly has to be $1$. Can you figure out what $\mathbb{P}[X\in[a+\frac{b-a}{2};b]]$ is?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily prove this using Moment Generating Function.

We know

> $M_{aX}(t)=M_X(at)$

$a$ in our case is $-1$

$M_X(t)=\dfrac{e^{bt}-e^{at}}{t(b-a)}$

$M_{(-X)}(t)=M_{X}(-t)=\dfrac{e^{-bt}-e^{-at}}{-t(b-a)}=\dfrac{e^{(-b)t}-e^{(-a)t}}{t(a-b)}$

You can see that it is MGF of uniform distribution but parameters are $-a$ and $-b$.

Therefor $-X \sim U(-b,-a)$