# Density Function of Uniform Distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

I had this problem from my last question:

Given that:
$X \sim \text{Uni}(a,b)$.

I know that the density function is:

$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{b-a} &x \in [a,b] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

Then How can this help me to find the density function of : $-X$?

Note: what is the right way to write the density function of : $-X$? will it be $f_{-X}(-x)$ or $f_{X}(-x)$ or $f_{-X}(x)$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given X is Uni, Prove -X is Uni?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3975065/given-x-is-uni-prove-x-is-uni)

Answer (score 0):

Just consider the cumulative distribution function:
$$F_X(x)=\int_a^x f_X(x) \quad dx=P(X<x)
$$ Then if $Y=-X$, by definition we have:
$$
F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(-X\leq y)=P(y\geq -X)=1-F_X(-x)
$$

So, again by definition: $f_Y(y)=F_Y'(y)=(-F_X(-x)
)'
=
f_X(-x)
$.

There you go. And the right way to write the density function of $-X$
would be $f_{-X}(-x)$, or more commonly:
$f_Y(y)$.

Comment: what is "a" in the integral?

Comment: f is the probability density function, my question is about "a"

Comment: Sorry, I misread, it's the $a$ in the interval $[a,b]$ of the definition of $f_X(x)$.

Comment: Are you sure of the last equality? (−(−))′= -1 * (−)′ = -1 * fX(-x)

Comment: Seems fine to me. What do you think it's wrong?

Comment: @miraunpajaro: it seems the integral $\int_a^x f(x)dx $ is the probability of taking values _ larger_ than x. Id suggest using different letters for the limits of integration and the variable of integration. Using the 'x' for both is confusing.